# How to fix "unfortunately , the process com.android.systemui has stopped" error?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, cyanogenmod

Recently, I flash `cm-11-20140504-SNAPSHOT-M6-maguro.zip` to my Galaxy Nexus GSM. And I flash PA gapps. And after that, I used Titanium backup to restore  all my applications. However, I met this `unfortunately , the process com.android.systemui has stopped` error sometimes. How can I fix it without doing a factory reset.

PS. If I enter the recovery and clear cache, it will be OK. However it is too annoying to do it each time. Is there other way to fix it. Or is it a bug in this version?

Refer:

- [Unfortunately, System UI has stopped](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49167/unfortunately-system-ui-has-stopped)
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/help/process-com-android-systemui-stopped-t1110673

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been experiencing this as well on the same build/phone.  A user on [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/development/rom-cyanogenmod-11-samsung-galaxy-nexus-t2525351/post52333075) claims that M5 may be much less error prone.

I haven't reverted to M5 yet myself.  When this error loop happens to me, I hold down the power button and try to select "reboot" between the times when I hit ok in the "Unfortunately... " box.

Comment: This may the related bug: https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-4047

Comment: After reading the bug thread a bit more, the change that caused the problem seems to have been reverted in the nightlies after may 17.  I am going to try this build tonight.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I flashed back to M5. It is much better and I never meet this problem again.

Comment: I have the same problem with Galaxy S3 in the last two snapshot builds. No way out.

Comment: flash back to early version